# Shoot photo in high quality, while capturing video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, photo, avcapture

**Hello,**

Is it possible to take a image in high quality, while viewing video with AVCapture in low quality? The problem is that i need to analyze the video (with a special algorithm, which takes too much time on high quality images, so i use low video quality) and then take a photo in high quality, when my algorithm says "just do it" :)

**Best regards**

Comment: What I once did was limiting the number of pixels to process by skipping N pixels in both X and Y direction.  So for example with N = 8, I used pixels at [0,0], [0,8] [0,16], ... [8,0], [8,8], [8,16], ...    If you're using library routines which do not allow you to skip pixels, it may work to create an intermediate image with these pixels, and feed that to the library routines.

Comment: Did you try creating 2 sessions, high and low resolution and then just start a high resolution when needed and end it after receiving first data?

Comment: Hi, thank's for the tips. I've managed it by doing everything in high quality, but i'm leaving out some frames to analize, but i will also try your solution with the 2 sessions, which will probably work too :)